# GoogleTest: How to catch a generic exception in EXPECT_THROW?

Tags: c++, exception, googletest, googlemock

Hi i want to catch a generic exception in function EXPECT_THROW **GoogleTest** ,which can catch all the type of exception thrown, irrespective of  exception type.

Is their any similar way as we used to catch in try-catch block.

```
catch (...) {
 
}
```

Comment: offtopic: Code which throws something which is not subclass of `std::exception` is a bad code. So basically test should not expect exception which is not covered by `catch(const std::exception&)`.

Comment: @MarekR no it isn't. Not following _some_ standard doesn't make your code bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EXPECT_ANY_THROW` is for this purpose.

See [Advanced googletest topics](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/assertions.html#exceptions).